# showing loading(progress) bar in firebase authentication android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, progress-bar

While authenticating with Firebase Auth I want to show a progress bar until data/request is loaded. I've tried to add a progress bar in xml and then setting its visibility to VISIBLE right before sending request to FirebaseAuth. Here is the code when application crashes

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                binding.pbLogin.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Wrong Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
            }
```

How can I show progress bar there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot touch views while using Dispathers.IO context. You should call

> binding.pbLogin.visibility = View.VISIBLE

before

> lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)

Or change your view's parameters using Dispatchers.Main context:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
       binding.pbLogin.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }          
}
```